# Change ImageView drawable vector color on touch

Tags: java, android, xml

My plan is to change the vector color from an ImageView in my RecyclerView adapter when the user touches the row. I just want to change the color from the touched row. I've wrote a code which should do this job but I'm getting an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.getColor(int)' on a null object reference
```

I've tried a lot but the error is always a problem.

This is my RecyclerView row xml:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Setting icon -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/settingImage"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:contentDescription="Icon"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <!-- Setting title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Setting subtitle -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingSubtitle"
        android:layout_below="@id/settingTitle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my vector graphic where I want to change the fill color:

```html
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/iconGray"
        android:pathData="M10.09 15.59L11.5 17l5-5-5-5-1.41 1.41L12.67 11H3v2h9.67l-2.58 2.59zM19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v4h2V5h14v14H5v-4H3v4c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z" />
</vector>
```

This is my adapter where I want to change the color on click:

```js
// Get setting holder type
holder.type = setting.getType();

// OnTouchListener for holder/vector color change
holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // Define setting holder
        MySettingHolder holder = (MySettingHolder) (v.getTag());

        // Set view for getting settingImage
        View view = (View)v.getParent();

        // ImageView for changing color
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.settingImage);

        // Define switch for line
        switch (holder.type) {
            // Case 1 = Logout
            case 1:
                // Change ImageView color
                DrawableCompat.setTint(imageView.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
                break;

            case 2:

                break;

            default:

                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Got it! Posting answer here later

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the context:

Old:

```js
DrawableCompat.setTint(imageView.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

New:

```js
DrawableCompat.setTint(imageView.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(v.getContext(), R.color.iconGray));
```